# how to show my contacts database value in my spinner?

Tags: android, database, spinner

In my layout xml I have a spinner and in my java I have a database with contacts and some values on it so I want to know how I send or put these values from the database in the spinner so when I click it, it selects the contact, any example of code?

Comment: No examples of code here. What have you tried?

Comment: actually i havent tried nothing because im a begginner and i dont know much, just wanna know how to show the values in the spinner

Comment: Start [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+spinner+tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the contacts details from the database first.
You can find a sample code for database concept at http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html .
Next from the above sample you may have got ArrayList of objects and set the contact names in the spinner using a

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Where list here may be the data from your ArrayList from the database. (store a specific field that you want to display from the database into this list).
Get the item selected using

```
spinner2.getSelectedItem()
```

which gives the item selected and get the data using from the ArrayList that you got from the database

Comment: thanks, i will have a look and do some tests, might reply later thanks

Comment: Hope this time in case of any issues you come back with a sample example that you did.
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
//Initialize  the spinner view
Spinner spinnerContact = (Spinnner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

//Initialise List Variable
List<String> contactsList = databaseObj.getContacts;

// Create and Implement Adapter for spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> contactAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, contactsList );

//set drop down view for spinner
contactAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

//set adapter for spinner
spinnerContact.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

//select the item in spinner defaultly
spinnerContact.setSelection(position);

//get Selected Item Text from the spinner
spinnerContact.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: databaseObj.getContacts || (position) , what are they and what do they mean? and are they variables? because they are giving errors

Comment: datbaseObj.getContacts means you write seperate method for getting contacts in a database helper class, and position is the index of the spinner values

Comment: k wait i will type now example., be patient

Answer (score 0):

Consider you in main Activty

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private List<String> contactList;
    private Spinner spinnerComp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinnerdemo);
       spinnerComp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getContacts());
    adapter                 .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerComp.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinnerComp.setSelection(0);
}
```

Now getContacts() containsas follows :

```
// get Contact Names
private List<String> getContacts() {
    // get Contacts
    List<Contact> contacts = DBHelper.getContacts();
    List<String> contactNames = null;
    if (contacts.size() != 0) {
        contactNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Contact contact : Contacts) {
            String contactName = contact.getName();
            contactNames.add(contactName);
        }

    } 
    return contactNames;
}
```

In DbHelper.java

```
  public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + Table.CONTACT + " ORDER BY " + 
        Contact.Column.NAME + " ASC";

    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Contact contact = getContactFromCursor(cursor);
        if(Contact != null) {
            contacts.add(Contact);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();

    return contacts;
}

private Contact getContactFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.Column.ID));
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.Column.NAME));
    long phoneNumber = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.Column.DATE_OF_BIRTH));
    Contact Contact = new Contact(name, phoneNumber);
    Contact.setId(id);
    return Contact;
}
```

Comment: i dont have the dbhelper i have these javas: Main, Novamensagem, Contato, Adicionarcontato |Contato to show the contacts already registred, Adicionarcontato for adding contact, Novamensagem to send a message( where the spinner is) and Main for the first screen to select what activity you want to go to.

Comment: you should write your own dbhelper class

Comment: k just send mail to rajeshmcashc10@gmail.com requesting dbhelper clas, i will forward the sample class. so that in future you can write your own dbhelper class