# How to see database values inside the spinner?

Tags: android, database, spinner

I have a spinner and a database so when i click the spinner i want to show the value(name) of the contacts in it but in a simple code. so they are separetated javas and xml layouts the spinner is in the (Novamensagem.java novamensagem.xml) and the contacs database is in the (Adicionarcontato.java adicionarcontato.xml) if you can specify and simply the code is better, thanks

```
    final TextView spinnerContato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};

    Cursor c = db.query("contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String lista = "";
    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
            lista = lista + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString() + "";
            if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }

        spinnerContato.setText(lista);
    }
```

thats the code but it gives the erros (more explained in comments)
//

the entire code:

```
ArrayList<String>() list = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.novamensagem);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("banco.db", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);

     SalvaMensagem();

    //Data e Hora
    setCurrentDateOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();
    setCurrentTimeOnView();
    addListenerOnButton2();

    //Spinner
    DadosSpinner();





}





private void DadosSpinner() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final TextView spinnerContato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = db.query("contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String lista = "";
    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString());
            if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);        
    }`
```

there is.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374659/how-to-show-my-contacts-database-value-in-my-spinner/12374760#comment16622049_12374760 It might be helpful to you

Comment: oh well thats my other question and oh i could of questioned there again, but as i said there is lets say, complicated and i want something simple because im new to it so if i can learn the real good basics better

Comment: oops actually did you design your database and is that working?

Comment: yeah its working because im testing to show its values in a textview and it work so i want to show them in the spinner now, i will edit a code in the question but when i use that i gives database error and closes the app.

Comment: You need to use an adapter like a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) to bind the data to your Spinner.

Comment: try to follow Sam's reply and be back if you are not getting it worked

Comment: no, im sorry i tried i read about it, seen some examples and i didnt understood it and also tested some examples but do not work and i just got confused haha :/

Comment: well where you got struck and what about the samples below?

Comment: Firstly get a spinner reference using findViewByid(..) and next get a List from the cursor object as in  link http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html and finally do what Marcin s did

Comment: ah its really confusing ahaha :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor c = db.query("contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
String lista = "";
if(c.getCount() > 0) {
    while(true) {
       list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString());
        if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
    }


}
```

This helps you to get an arrayList of items.

Next do this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);


adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Be back if you have any issues

Answer (score 1):

To load the spinner data from SQLite database you have to:

1. Read the contacts from database and save it into the list (for example)
2. Create an adapter for the spinner

Method would look like this:

```
 private void loadSpinnerData() 
 {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, contacts);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 }
```

And getAllContacts() method will return all the contacts:

```
public List<String> getAllConatcts(){
    List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contacts.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning contatcs
    return contacts;
}
```

For more information check this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/

Comment: can you tell me what do i have to change into my variables?

Comment: Instead of simplecursoradapter you use array adapter as shown above

Comment: yeah ok but i already have the tables,columns and the data and i dont understand .getAllContacts (its giving errors here) and i dont see anything connecting to the database in the databasehandler.java

Comment: In the sample getAllContacts is a method which may return an List

Comment: I have edited an answer and attached getAllContacts() method.

Comment: well i tried it and setted up everything butt doesnt work when i compile nothing happens no data value shows up :/